# Routes in production does not work on page reload

Tags: angular

Angular route on page reload is not working in production (pcf).

When a route is loaded using an anchor link (button) route works fine. But, when the same page is reloaded I get page not found error (404).

route module:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: DComponent },
  { path: 'c', component: CComponent },
  { path: 'v-c/:id', component: VCComponent },
]),
```

path: `v-c/:id` works fine when opened using an anchor link(button) but gives 404 not found on reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be problem with missing web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Add it into src and dont forget add to `angular.json` in `assets`

or

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="redirect all" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="./" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

if you are use `#`
check

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

Comment: Can I use the same config file and use `ng build` without any flags ? our url does not contain `/api` so, do I have to change `pattern="^/(api)`?

Comment: yes, but be sure that web.config pressents on dist folfer after build

Comment: I am still getting 404, web config is present in dist after build

Comment: change to 
 <action type="Rewrite" url="./" appendQueryString="true" />

Comment: and In index.html is <base href="./">. Refreshing the page is now ok.

Comment: add additional web.config

Comment: I have used the new web.config as you suggested, still getting 404. Do I have to use `LocationStrategy` ?

Comment: Does yours url path contains '#'?

Comment: With LocationStrategy, its working fine. Thank you.